# Добавление аккордеона на сформированной html таблице

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, table

Ищу реализацию таблицы с аккордеоном, один из тех вариантов который нашел:
http://jsfiddle.net/Xqk3m/2/
в данном случае таблица формируется с элементами которым передается параметр `hide`,
Посоветуйте, если есть ли подобные решения/наброски, но, для уже сформированной таблице, по клику добавлять `tr` с раскрытием  куда уже буду подтягивать данные